# Using MinGW C compiler instead of Microsoft Visual Studio Express for Python

Tags: python, c, windows, mingw

I am trying to install the python Package pyOpt and have difficulties using Microsoft Visual Studio Express because I am running a 64 bit install of Python.

The pyOpt developers recommend using MinGW-W64 if the system doesn't have access to other c/Fortran compilers.

I have now installed MinGW-W64 but it seems like the standard `python setup.py install` seems to still want to use VS.

How do I tell the installer to rather use MinGW's compiler instead? Should MinGW come with the necessary c compiler out of the box or must I first install one in MinGW?

Comment: Python requires a specific version of the MS compiler on Windows. You don't get a choice in the matter. The 64 bit compilers are readily available though.

Comment: Thank you Davis. Are you referring to the MinGW compiler that is readily available? Or do you mean Python can't use MinGW compilers and must use the 'specific version of the MS compiler'?

Comment: Python C modules have to be compiled with specific MS compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Just start `%APPDATA%\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\vcvarsall.bat amd64` and you will get environment for 64-bit Python
2. MinGW compiler needs lot of tweaking in order to link with correct `msvcr90.dll` library but compiling with MinGW possible too - http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Use_the_GCC_specs_file